# X~B(5,$\frac{1}{2}$) and Y~U(0,1) Then $\frac{P(X+Y\leq2)}{P(X+Y\geq5)}$=?

Tags: probability, statistics

$X\sim\text{Bin}\left(5,\frac{1}{2}\right)$ and $Y\sim \text{Unif}(0,1).$ 
Then $\frac{P(X+Y\leq2)}{P(X+Y\geq5)}$=?

Intuitively $X+Y$ takes values from $[0,6)$ since $X$ takes $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $Y$ takes $(0,1)$. Let $Z = X+Y$,
$P(Z\leq z)=0$ if $z<0$.
How to define $P(Z\leq z)$ if $0\leq z\leq 6$?

Comment: Hint: $X$ is integer valued and $0<Y<1$ almost surely hence $X+Y\leqslant2\iff X\leqslant\ldots$.

Comment: @Did Hallo, and I wish you a nice 2016. I am very glad to see you back!! I really missed you.

Comment: @drhab Nice to say so. Happy 2016 to you too.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

If $n\in\mathbb Z$ then $z\geq n\iff\lfloor z\rfloor\geq n$.

If moreover $z\notin\mathbb Z$ then $z\leq n\iff\lfloor z\rfloor\leq n-1$.

Now realize that $X=\lfloor X+Y\rfloor$ a.s. and $X+Y\notin\mathbb Z$ a.s..

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Thus, 
$$P(Z \leq z) = P(X+Y\leq z) = \sum_{k=0}^ 5P(X = k)P(X+Y \leq z|X =k)
=\sum_{k=0}^ 5P(X = k)P(Y \leq z-k)$$
where the last step is true since $X$ and $Y$ are independent. This is the discrete convolution (formula).
This should help you take care of the numerator.

As for the denominator, it's a similar idea.
Notice that $X$ has to be at least $4$, thus
$$P(X+Y \geq 5) = \sum_{k=4}^5 P(X = k)P(Y\geq 5-k).$$

Comment: This can be much simplified and, as already explained in a comment, the independence of $X$ and $Y$ is not even needed to solve the question asked (which is *not* to determine the distribution of $X+Y$, only to compute $P(X+Y\le2)$ and $P(X+Y\ge5)$...).

Comment: @Did Simplified, sure you can see that but may not OP. As for $Z$, the very last question was "How to define $P(Z \leq z)$..."

Comment: If this can be simplified, the job of any answerer is to simplify it, right? For the maths, see @drhab's answer.

Comment: @Did No I disagree. It is possible to simplify and get to answer much quicker. It is also possible to simplify and confuse the person asking the question more. The same can be said for complicating\writing out all the step (like I did).

Comment: But if one can simplify without confusing, this is provably better than any other option, right? So, let us do that when we can (and here, we can)!

Comment: @Did Sure, it won't confuse _you_ but you don't know what OP's thinking or their experience level. It might not confuse you but it might confuse them. This is a forum for people to post a variety of answers and strategies to help the questioner. It's up to the OP to decide which response was best for his/her needs.

Comment: These awfully general considerations of yours look more and more like stonewalling, I am afraid. Indeed we cannot be 100% sure of the way any answer will be understood by any asker, never, and so what? The matter of interest should be whether the (mostly irrelevant) considerations in your post help more, a priori, than the (precise and to the point) remarks made in the other answer, say.

Comment: @Did Sure, so what?

Comment: So we are back to "If this can be simplified, the job of any answerer is to simplify it", right?